# Can this idea be extended to an Uncountable Index.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So , I was surfing some exam papers Isi JRF mathematics I found an interesting Problem about rings,but here is the generalization of that problem.

$\textbf{Theorem:}$Let, $R$ be some commutative ring with unity such that for $a_{i}\in R$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$  there exist $x_{i}\in R$ such that $$\sum_{i}^{n} a_{i}x_{i}=1$$ given that for any finite sequence define by $b_{i}$ with $1\leq i\leq n$ then there exist a sequence $\alpha_{j}\in R$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$ such that we have
$$\boxed{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}a_{k}^{b_{k}}=1}$$
$\textbf{Proof:}$Multinomial Theorem works fine as $R$ is a commutative ring with unity.$\blacksquare$

So for those who know the solution I wanna ask that does can this be extented to an uncountable index such that this holds because the key thing in proving the theorem above doen't hold for uncountable index so can't possibly genralize it over uncountable index set.

$\textbf{Remark:}$Obvio for my question I had taken R is taken to be uncountable(not necessary for theorem mentioned though).

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble parsing this question. am I right that your assumption on $R$ is that, for any finite sequence $a_1,\dots,a_n\in R$ of elements of $R$, there exist elements $x_1,\dots,x_n\in R$ such that $a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n=1$? if so, this condition is never satisfied unless $R$ is the zero ring, as taking $n=1$ and $a_1=0$ gives the equation $x_10=1$ which is unsolvable unless $R$ is the zero ring

Comment: also, what do you mean by "uncountable index set"? in an arbitrary ring $R$ there is no way in general to make sense of a sum $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$ where $I$ is infinite

Comment: Not for any if there exist such R I am saying

Comment: okay, so you are starting with the assumption that $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is a sequence of elements such that $\langle a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle=R$. fair enough! but that still leaves the issue that infinite sums are not meaningful in arbitrary rings

Comment: If I restrict The ring to some Uncoutable ring. I mean is there any notion like $R=<a_{\lambda}>$ where $\lambda\in I$ is an indexing set. I mean can we do it for some ring R.i

Comment: sure! given any sequence $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ you can always look at the ideal $\langle a_i:i\in I\rangle$ generated by all of the $a_i$. however, if this ideal is equal to $R$, then there exist finitely many $i_1,\dots,i_n\in I$ such that $\langle a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_n}\rangle=R$ – do you see why this is?

Comment: Intersection right?

Comment: Another last doubt I have is is there any ring R which is commutative with 1 such that it has uncountable number of generators?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by intersection; here's the argument I had in mind. since $\langle a_i:i\in I\rangle=R$, in particular $1$ lies in that ideal, so by definition of the ideal there exist $i_1,\dots,i_n\in I$ and $x_1,\dots,x_n\in R$ such that $1=x_1a_{i_1}+\dots+x_na_{i_n}$. in particular this means $\langle a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_n}\rangle=R$, as needed

Comment: regarding your second question – yes, absolutely! in fact, if $R$ is *any* uncountable ring, then $R$ cannot be generated (as a ring) by countably many generators. this is a good exercise, ie try to show that any countably generated ring is countable